# Bottom nav bar with curved edge and shadow- Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, shadow, android-bottomnav

I am trying to build a bottom nav bar with curved edges at the top start and top end.
When setting a shadow, it is not showing the shadow correctly.
How to set a shadow around? Or am I doing any wrong thing?

**Code**

```
BottomNavigation(
    backgroundColor = Color(0xffffff),
    modifier = Modifier
        .graphicsLayer {
            clip = true
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 30.dp, topEnd = 30.dp)
            shadowElevation = 2.2f
        }
        .height(100.dp),
    elevation = 8.dp,
)
```

**Screenshot**

[image: my failed result]

How to add a shadow around the top start and end edges?

Comment: I actually see the shadow on your image, try increasing `shadowElevation`

Comment: I did it . But still its giving the same .

Comment: Its the background color set to gray of the page not shadow

Comment: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaD3k.gif) is how [this code](https://gist.github.com/PhilipDukhov/a492cf97f221cff6096446413623c0a6) works to me - `shadowElevation` definitely works